# Tomcat vs Jetty JNDI Lookup

Tags: spring, tomcat, jetty, tomcat6, jndi

I use Spring to configure my Java Web App and in my Spring configuration I obtain a datasource via JNDI for Jetty as follows:

`<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/myDataSource" />`

but this won't work with Tomcat.  With Tomcat I have to do this:

`<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource" />`

Whats the best way to solve this?  I am already using JNDI as a way to externalize configuration, so I can't externalize my externalized configuration!  At the same time I absolutely loath the idea of having two separate Spring configuration files. HELP!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an answer [here](http://blog.vinodsingh.com/2008/12/jndi-lookup-on-tomcat-and-jboss-using.html), but I thought it was a bit complicated, but it did give me the idea to use the very cool [ServerDetector](http://svn.liferay.com/browse/~raw,r=60314/portal/trunk/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/ServerDetector.java) class that blogger had found.

Once I can dynamically figure what type of server I am running in, I was able to use the Spring expression language to do the rest of the work:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myAppDataSource" 
    jndi-name="#{ (AppServerType == 'Jetty' ? 'jdbc/' : 'java:comp/env/jdbc/') + 
                  'myAppDataSource' }" />
```

Easy!

Answer (score 5):

After some experimenting, I figured out I could just force Jetty to use the same JNDI path as Tomcat.  The following snippet is from my `jetty-env.xml` file:

```
 <New id="myDataSource" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
  <!-- We MUST specify the entire JNDI path here to force compliance with the Tomcat/J2EE convention -->
  <Arg>java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource</Arg>
  <Arg>
   <New class="com.atomikos.jdbc.nonxa.AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean">
    <Set name="uniqueResourceName">sbeDatabase</Set>
                 ...............
   </New>
  </Arg>
 </New>
```

Not sure if this is ideal, but it works.

**Update**:

It works if you put your jetty-env.xml file inside the WAR...but for whatever reason, one you move this configuration outside the WAR and into a context fragment file in Jetty's "contexts" directory then it throws an exception:

Check it out:  http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-273

Comment: I like this because it doesn't rely on that xml cancer that Spring is.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do it is to configure your configuration. ;)

Use a Spring property place holder.  See

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer

The basic idea is that you just put a placeholder in your spring config with a property, and then it reads matching property from a properties file.  You generate the properties file in your build process.  Ive seen it done where the build tool (ant) reads an environment variable and then creates a properties file appropriate for the environment based of a skeleton file populated with tokens.

Comment: Are you saying to then use this value from the property placeholder as the jndi-name?  Or to skip JNDI altogether?

Comment: @hdave, configure jndi-name to be ="{jndi.name}", where jndi.name is a property in a buildfile that is generated by your build process. Seems you solved the issue, but this technique will definitely be useful to you eventually.

Comment: I think it will as I'll be moving towards support for Websphere soon and I understand it has its own funky approach towards JNDI paths.

Comment: I just realized that this approach will result in an app-server specific WAR file because it will have a filtered properties file inside it.  I am looking for a single approach that will dynamically adjust itself based on the app-server.